# JIRA Plugin Development: Active objects : AO Table doesnt exist

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am getting this error when I am trying to persist some entries in AO in my plugin

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'jirainfra.AO_4E216C_EVENT_DB' doesn't exist

Now I do have an entity called EventDB set up in code.

Not sure why is this showing up. Any ideas/fixes?

Comment: Do you have <ao> definition in your atlassian-plugin.xml? Additionaly it would be good to see your code the does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ao key="ao-module">
  <description>The configuration of the Active Objects service</description>
  <entity>com.path.to.plugin.classAO</entity>
</ao>
```

Maybe ActiveObjects is missing in atlassian-plugin.xml ?